# Azure file copy to blob failing

Tags: azure-devops

Trying the Azure file copy for the first time so not sure where I'm going wrong as it keeps failing with the details seen further below. It does create the 'Test' container though.

Also tried by changing the task version to 2 and 3. Same result

Any suggestions where to start looking?

Copied from 'View Yaml'

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/interace/interface brands/v20.08'
    azureSubscription: Development
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: updates
    ContainerName: Test
```

Log output:

```
2020-08-20T12:51:39.0807389Z INFO: AzCopy.exe: A newer version 10.6.0 is available to download
2020-08-20T12:51:39.0810239Z 
2020-08-20T12:51:39.0923021Z ##[debug]Trying to disconnect from Azure and clear context at process scope
2020-08-20T12:51:39.0975253Z ##[debug]Cannot verify the Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.2 because it is not included in the list of permitted versions.
2020-08-20T12:51:39.0997871Z ##[debug]Populating RepositorySourceLocation property for module Az.Accounts.
2020-08-20T12:51:39.1022385Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\Modules\az_3.1.0\Az.Accounts\1.9.2\Az.Accounts.psm1'.
2020-08-20T12:51:39.1250145Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-08-20T12:51:39.5095303Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-08-20T12:51:40.0741695Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2020-08-20T12:51:40.0773655Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1256747Z ##[debug]Upload to container: 'test' in storage account: 'updates' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1267682Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\4.171.3\Utility.ps1:109 char:5
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1278911Z ##[debug]+     throw "$errorMessage $helpMessage"
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1290483Z ##[debug]+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1301825Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Upload to conta...efilecopyreadme:String) [], RuntimeException
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1313423Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Upload to container: 'test' in storage account: 'updates' with blob prefix: '' fa    iled with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info     please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1323723Z ##[debug] 
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1343144Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1387327Z ##[debug]at ThrowError, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\4.171.3\Utility.ps1: line 109
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1399427Z ##[debug]at Upload-FilesToAzureContainer, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\4.171.3\Utility.ps1: line 248
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1410626Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzureFileCopy_eb72cb01-a7e5-427b-a8a1-1b31ccac8a43\4.171.3\AzureFileCopy.ps1: line 181
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1421592Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1433593Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1445293Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1456696Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1475711Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1517637Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Upload to container: 'test' in storage account: 'updates' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1704018Z ##[error]Upload to container: 'test' in storage account: 'updates' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1706605Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Upload to container: 'test' in storage account: 'updates' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
2020-08-20T12:51:40.1726755Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2020-08-20T12:51:40.2315295Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureBlob File Copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure file copy to blob failing

Since you tested the task version to 2 and 3 and got the same error, I guess there might be something wrong with authentication error from Azure instead of the task itsself.

We need to make sure the Service Principal we use in this task have access to the Storage Account. You could try to navigate to `Storage accounts`
-> `Access control` page and `Add a role assignment`(Storage Blob Data Contributor/owner role) to my Service Principal/Managed Identity:

[image]

Besides, check also your Service Connection in your Azure DevOps Project Settings for identifying that you are using the correct Resource Group.

You could check [this thread](https://gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/7611/612676613) for some more details.

Comment: Added the role and it looks like this solved the issue as it progressed a bit further. 
(Now fails with error parsing source location.) Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, adding the role resolved the issue. The content was copied to the container (parsing error was me forgetting to enable artifact download)